# Directed cage graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A [cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_(graph_theory)) is a smallest undirected graph with the following two properties (for some constants $r,g$):

- Each node has exactly $r$ neighbors;
- The smallest cycle has exactly $g$ nodes.

When $r=2$ a cage is just a cycle with $g$ nodes, so cages usually become interesting only for $r\geq 3$.

I am interested in a "directed cage": a smallest directed graph with the following properties:

- Each node has exactly $r$ outgoing edges;
- The smallest *undirected* cycle (- a cycle in which the edge directions are ignored) has exactly $g$ nodes.

MY QUESTION IS: Is anything known about such "directed cages"?

Specifically: how many nodes are needed for a directed cage when $r=2$, as a function of $g$?

Comment: For $r=2$, there is an obvious graph with $2(g+1)$ vertices.  Can you do better? In the other direction, the case $g=3$ includes the Caccetta–Haggkvist conjecture so it is very hard.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay In the obvious graph with $2(g+1)$ vertices, does the smallest *directed* cycle have $g$ nodes? Or the smallest *undirected* cycle?

Comment: Are your graphs strictly directed? In other words, do you allow the presence of both an edge and its reverse?

If yes, then it seems to me that a cycle of length 2 is the answer. (Where we think of the cycle as having edges in both direction.)

If no, then it seems to me that the answer is simply the size of an undirected (4,g)-cage. Indeed, in this case, the underlying graph of the digraph is 4-valent and has girth g, while any 4-valent graph of girth g can have its edges oriented to yield a directed graph of out-valency 2 (using an Eulerian circuit say).

Comment: It seems to me that, either way, the question is equivalent to the cage problem for undirected graphs, either of valency 2 or of valency 4.

Comment: @Erel: Please define what you mean by an "undirected cycle" in a directed graph. If you just mean that the edges of the cycle don't need to be directed consistently (some can point one way and some the other way) then the fact you are dealing with digraphs is almost irrelevant, as in Verret's comment.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I can't think of any other natural definition...

Comment: @verret if $g>2$, then obviously we cannot have both an edge and its reverse, since this creates a cycle of length 2.

Comment: @verret I understand that any undirected (4,g)-cage is a directed (2,g)-cage, since the edges can be directed using an Eulerian circuit. But why is the opposite true?  (why is any directed (2,g)-cage an undirected (4,g)-cage?)

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Why not answer Brendan's question first?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Yes, by "undirected cycle" I mean a cycle where the edge directions are ignored. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: @verret: When there are no 2-cycles, the underlying undirected graph has average degree 4 but it doesn't have to be 4-regular. So the question is whether there are irregular examples that are smaller than regular examples.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Right, I assumed that the in-valency was also 2.